# React UseEffect api calls mapping arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am fetching two object arrays from api backend and joined by id if exists, all of them in useEffect.

I am confusing, cause if write "console.log" whole info is on screen but if comment or delete console cant watch nothing on screen.

Any help?

Using react and material

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useAuth } from "../../contexts/Auth";
import { supabase } from "../../lib/supabase";
import {
  Avatar,
  Grid,
  Container,
  Typography,
  Button,
  Box,
} from "@mui/material";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider, styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const HiklubTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#7c378a",
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#93c01f",
    },
  },
});

const StyledAffinityTypo = styled(
  Typography,
  {}
)({
  color: "white",
  backgroundColor: "#93c01f",
  padding: "0.5rem",
  maxWidth: "100%",
  fontFamily: ["Asap"],
});

const StyledKluberAvatar = styled(
  Avatar,
  {}
)({
  width: "4rem",
  height: "4rem",
  objectFit: "contain",
});

export default function ListCustomerBooked({ id }) {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
  const [scores, setScores] = useState([]);
  const [CustomerScore, setCustomerScore] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchCustomer(id) {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        let { data, error, status } = await supabase
          .from("customers")
          .select("*")
          .eq("customer", id);

        if (error && status !== 406) {
          throw error;
        }
        if (data) {
          // remove customer from array
          data = data.filter((el) => el.customers.id !== user.id);
          const items = data.map((object) => ({
            token: object.token,
            customer_id: object.id,
            email: object.email,
            firstname: object.firstname,
          }));
          setCustomers(items);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error.message);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }

    async function fetchCustomerScores() {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        let { data, error, status } = await supabase
          .from("scores")
          .select("*")
          .eq("customer_id", user.id);

        if (error && status !== 406) {
          throw error;
        }
        setScores((scores) => [...scores, ...data]);
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error.message);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }

    fetchCustomer(id);
    fetchCustomerScores();

    // Map two arrays and add score
    setCustomerScore(
      customers.map((t1) => ({
        ...t1,
        ...scores.find((t2) => t2.customer_id === t1.customer_id ),
      }))
    );
  }, [id]);

return (
    <Container sx={{ my: "2rem" }}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item>
          <Typography variant="h5" sx={{ fontWeight: "bold", my: "1rem" }}>
            {" "}
            Count customers ({customers.length + 1}){" "}
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid container sx={{ my: "3rem" }}>
        {CustomerScore.map((customer, index) => (
          <Grid key={index} item xs={3}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={HiklubTheme}>
              <StyledKluberAvatar
                alt={customer.email}
                color="secondary"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1542740348-39501cd6e2b4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=387&q=80"
              ></StyledKluberAvatar>
            </ThemeProvider>

            {!customer.score ? (
              <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: "light" }}>
                No customer's score
              </Typography>
            ) : (
              <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: "light" }}>
                {parseFloat(customer.score).toFixed(0)} %
              </Typography>
            )}
            <ThemeProvider theme={HiklubTheme}>
              {!customer.firstname ? (
                <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: "light" }}>
                  {customer.firstname}
                </Typography>
              ) : (
                <Typography sx={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>
                  {customer.email}
                </Typography>
              )}
            </ThemeProvider>
          </Grid>
        ))}
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Not rendering on screen,

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

As `fetchCustomer` and `fetchCustomerScores` are async

try

```
async function loadData() {
    await fetchCustomer(id);
    await fetchCustomerScores();

    // Map two arrays and add score
    setCustomerScore(
      customers.map((t1) => ({
        ...t1,
        ...scores.find((t2) => t2.customer_id === t1.customer_id ),
      }))
    );
}
loadData();
```

in place of

```
    fetchCustomer(id);
    fetchCustomerScores();

    // Map two arrays and add score
    setCustomerScore(
      customers.map((t1) => ({
        ...t1,
        ...scores.find((t2) => t2.customer_id === t1.customer_id ),
      }))
    );
```